# Is it good practice to add an event listener within a function containing parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-events

I would just like to know if it is good practice to have a click event listener in a function like the example below. (Don't try to understand what the code does, I just wanted to show an example of a situation where a click event is in a function )

```
function someFn(classClickedBtn, popupId) {

            $(classClickedBtn).click(function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               var active = "active";
               var mainClass = ".dialogBox";

                  if ( $(popupId).hasClass(active) ) {

                        $(popupId).removeClass(active);

                    }else{

                        for (var i = 0; i< $(mainClass).length; i++) {
                        if ( $(mainClass).hasClass("active") ) {
                        $(mainClass).removeClass("active"); } }

                        $(popupId).addClass(active);

                    }

            });

         }


        someFn(".btn1", "#popup");

        someFn(".btn2", "#popup");
```

Comment: It's not wrong, but it can easily lead to mistakes. I'd suggest `$(triggerBtnClass).off("click.namespace").on("click.namespace",function(e) { ... });` to ensure that even if you call the function repeatedly, only one event listener will be added.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to attach an event handler for 'click' event of 'triggerBtnClass', only if something call your function before, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm okay with calling the listener from within your function. You can make things a little easier on yourself by calling the function one time with all arguments included. Have a look at the refactored code below. I'm using an object literal to store the function arguments and calling the function one time, passing the object as a single parameter.

```js
function someFn(fn_data) {
  $(fn_data.btns).on("click", function(e) {
    var active = "active";
    var mainClass = $(".dialogBox");
    var popup = $(fn_data.popupId);
    
    e.preventDefault();  
    
    if (popup.hasClass(active)) {
      popup.removeClass(active);
    } else {
    
      for (var i = 0; i < mainClass.length; i++) {
        if ( mainClass.hasClass("active") ) {
          mainClass.removeClass("active"); 
        } 
      }

      popup.addClass(active);
    }
  });
}

someFn({
  btns: ".btn1, .btn2",
  popupId: "#popup"
});
```

```css
#popup {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

#popup.active:after {
  content: 'Popup active!';
}

#popup:after {
  content: 'Popup not active!';
  color: #555;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;  
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1">button 1</button>
<button class="btn2">button 2</button>
<div id="popup">popup goes here</div>
```